# Characteristic function of uniform random variable

Tags: density-function, uniform-distribution, characteristic-function

I am trying to find out expectation of a function of a uniform random variable. I am given a random variable $x$ that is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, a]$. I want to find out the expectation $E[e^{-i2\pi (m-n)\frac{x}{a}}]$, where $m$, $n$ are integers and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

I saw derivation at a few places, and it looks like that the expectation evaluates to $\delta_{km}$. It is not clear to me how this derivation is carried out. When I look at the expectation, it appears I am trying to calculate the characteristic function of a uniform random variable. This function is not a delta function. So what am I missing here?

Comment: I am not sure that it is a duplicate.   The question was about U[01] and the characteristic function wasn't mentioned.  It is only in the long answer of whuber that you see the characteristic function. The OP is using U[0,a].  Maybe that doesn't matter.  But could he be talking about a uniform with an unknown parameter a?

Comment: You can find the derivation [here](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/uniform-distribution).